# C - how to keep variable

Tags: c, static, int

I would like know how I can keep the text in the txt variable? I would like to keep it unitl my function will end - I think it's called static int

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    char txt[100];
    printf("Insert a text: ");
    fgets(txt, 100, stdin);
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "echo '%s'", txt);
    system(buf);
}
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: `txt` will be preserved until its scope ends. Can you clarify your question please? What exactly is the problem with the above code?

Comment: "*I would like to keep it unitl my function will end*" It already does

Comment: If you mark it is static, it will be preserved until your *program* ends.  Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Sorry about that, I would keep it until program end

Comment: in this case the end of the function is the end of the programm

Comment: Then it's not working, because when I'm adding another system function for example system("echo '%d', buf); then I'm getting error: too many arguments to function ‘system’  note: declared here
 extern int system (const char *__command) __wur;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got has nothing to do with the scope of `buf`.
It refers to the `system` function which expects only one parameter:

```
int system(const char *command)
```

Hope I helped.